# Does consuming an Atom feed require AtomPub?

Tags: atom-feed, atompub

I would like to create a simple endpoint which generates an Atom 1.0 or RSS 2.0 feed.

My understanding is that as long as the output is valid Atom or RSS XML, browsers and feed readers should be able to access and use this. Is this correct?

Does my endpoint have to support AtomPub protocol as well or simple HTTP GET is enough? I think AtomPub is for publishing and resource management only, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that as long as the output is valid Atom or RSS XML, browsers and feed readers should be able to access and use this. Is this correct?

Yes.

> I think AtomPub is for publishing and resource management only, right?

Yes.